# cordova-plugin-googlemaps: Uncaught ReferenceError: plugin is not defined

Tags: cordova

I cant get the googlemaps plugin to work in phonegap.
I have added the keys for ios and android
I have added the plugin information in config.xml
It is in my plugin list

my code:

```
plugin.google.maps.Map.isAvailable(function(isAvailable, message) {
    if (isAvailable) {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new plugin.google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
            zoom: 6,
            mapTypeId: plugin.google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
var map = new plugin.google.maps.Map($("#map_canvas").get(0),mapOptions);


    map.addEventListener(plugin.google.maps.event.MAP_READY, onMapReady);
    } else {
        alert(message);
    }

});
```

Hope somebody have some ideas

Comment: Are you testing on a computer? Also, are you firing after onDeviceReady? http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html

Comment: I'm testing it on my iphone and in a browser. Yes I'm firing onDeviceReady

Comment: Maybe this pull request work for you. https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/pull/1398